# Prove that $1/(\sin x + 1) - 1/(\sin x - 1) = 2 \sec^2 (x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Can anyone solve this for me?

> Prove that $\frac1{\sin x + 1} - \frac1{\sin x - 1} = 2 \sec^2 (x)$.

This is as far as I went:

$$\frac{(sin x - 1) - (sin x + 1)}{(sin x + 1)(sin x - 1)}$$

$$=\frac{sin x -1 - sin x -1}{sin^2 (x) + 1^2
}$$

$$=\frac{-2}{sin^2 (x) + 1}$$

What to do next?

I am new here, and currently in high-school, so don't make it too complicated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please show us what you tried to solve the question. This will also help us identify what you know so we can give appropriate answers.

Comment: As AlexR already said, you should show us some of your attempt and where you got stuck while solving this problem. You can do this by clicking the "edit" button under your question, then add your attempt under what you already wrote in your question.

Comment: that's $\sin^2{x}-1^2$, not $\sin^2{x}+1^2$...

Comment: It looks like you're close.  You just made a mistake with a sign in the denominator.

Comment: @hkmather802 hehe.. got it wrong. Thanks for pointing that out. I can go on now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding a common denominator and simplifying the numerator, the LHS becomes

$$ \dfrac{-2}{(\sin(x)-1)(\sin(x)+1)}$$

The denominator is a difference of squares, and using the pythagorean identity will yield the desired result.